# How to store xml as a field in elasticsearch?

Tags: json, xml, elasticsearch

I want to store an xml as a field in elasticsearch. My purpose is just to store the xml and retrieve it. I do not want to perform any searches on the xml data.

```
**Sample xml** : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample>
<name>abc</name>
</sample>
```

Note : I don't want to convert xml into json. I want to directly write this sample xml as-is in elasticsearch index and just wanted to retrieve it once it is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way of solving this problem but what I figured out is 
while posting data into ES provide three double quotes (""") instead of one ("). That's a temporary solution I guess :

```
POST my_index/test 
{ 
   "xml" : """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
              <sample> 
              <name>abc</name> 
              </sample>""" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't intend to use the field for search and simply retrieval I'd suggest you add a simple "xml" string field in your mapping like below (it looks probably strange to use a "keyword" type, but it's the only string field that can be configured not to be analyzed)

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "xml": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But by using your way I have to format the xml first I mean replacing the next lines with '\n' and replacing the double quotes with single quotes. Is there any direct way to add the sample xml as a field without doing any modification to the mentioned sample xml.

Comment: @Sid Why would you need to replace anything from the input xml? As far as I am aware, ES does not modify your input, perhaps I have missed something that you could clarify for me

Comment: This is how I am providing input to ES : `POST my_index/test
{
  "xml" : "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample>
<name>abc</name>
</sample>"
}`

Comment: This is giving me an error : `{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@7f4bf48c; line: 2, column: 28]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}`

Comment: @Sid My bad, indeed you need to provide a valid JSON to ES, and you cannot escape doing these modifications as far as I am aware (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/jsonparseexception-illegal-unquoted-character-ctrl-char-code-9-has-to-be-escaped/12410/2). As far as I know there are no plugins allowing to give such an input without raising an exception. If modifying the xml before indexing is out of question, I'd suggest not using ES but Solr which supports natively XML

Comment: @aserrouf check my answer.

Comment: Doing a little modification